# Trouble reading .mat files in Python

Tags: python, matlab, file, scipy, mat-file

Whenever I try to read a `.mat` file in Python, I get the following error message

*ValueError: Unknown mat file type, version 9, 99*

The particular dataset I want to open is [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE137764), named "GSE137764_HCT_GaussiansGSE137764_mooth_scaled_autosome.mat".

I have tried to follow the multiple solutions available here, but I keep getting the same error. In particular, I do not use MATLAB, so I can't really do `save('myfile.mat','-v7')`, for example. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It is a "normal" csv file, just not named like one.

```
pd.read_csv("GSE137764_HCT_GaussiansGSE137764_mooth_scaled_autosome.mat", delimiter="\t", low_memory=False)
```

Comment: How would you select only the entries with header `chr1`, for example?

Comment: Pandas will rename the columns to be unique, so you have chr1, chr1.1  **1)** You could use `read_csv` with `header=None`, this will then write the chrX into the first row, after wards you can use boolean indexing, which is similar to the method where you **2) keep the headers**: `df.loc[:, df.columns.str.match("chr1($|\.)")]` `chr1` is the type you want to match `($|\.)` means either end of string($) or the alternative `.X` where X is the number of the duplicated column. NOTE: Likewise you can **3) rename** the columns with `df.columns = df.columns.str.extract("(chr\d+)").values.flatten()`